# How Could I Check the Highest, Second Highest, Third Highest, etc. of a Set of Values in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a random Dungeons and Dragons character generator on Python 3, and I am at the point of rolling for ability scores, and I was wondering how to get the highest, second highest, third highest, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague, but here's a general solution. Just sort your data in descending order.

```
for val in sorted (myset, reverse=True):
    print val
```

Answer (score 0):

use if condition while giving option like num1 num2 num3 and then compare and print the large by doing in if condition like if(num1>num2) then print the one option and another with else .try out

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this:

```
dice_list.sort()
dice_list.reverse()
for dice in dice_list:
        print(dice)
```

Comment: By the way, why don't you just roll a die 3 times and see which one is the highest, 2nd highest and lowest? It's a lot fairer. Sometimes coding languages 'favour' a number.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to give you a website which has loads of D&D stuff. https://dnd.beyond.com and https://dnd.wizards.com